# combine list elements

Tags: python

How can I merge/combine two or three elements of a list. For instance, if there are two elements, the list 'l'

```
l = [(a,b,c,d,e),(1,2,3,4,5)]
```

is merged into

```
[(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4),(e,5)]
```

however if there are three elements

```
l = [(a,b,c,d,e),(1,2,3,4,5),(I,II,II,IV,V)]
```

the list is converted into

```
[(a,1,I),(b,2,II),(c,3,III),(d,4,Iv),(e,5,V)]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the quotes from your strings and you have I,II,II, The operation by zip(*l) is actually same as transposing a matrix.

Comment: `list(*zip(*zip(l))) == l` for any list l ...

Comment: @Tony, who says they're strings?

Comment: @Aaron logic of simplified example cases to the forum by begginers. and the mistake in the roman sequence to be congruent with latin numbers: sequence of alphabet, sequence of latin numbers, sequence of roman numbers. I do not think they are meant to be variables or functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
print zip(*l)
```

Result:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Btw, how do I remove inner parenthesis in: 
(a, (1,2)) so I get a list like: (a,1,2)? Thanks again.

Comment: @DGT You can use `itertools.chain`.