# I want to all list element stacked

Tags: python, list

Is there any way to stack list

```
lis = [['a','b'],
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['r', 's', 't','u']]
```

i hope return

```
['a1r','a1s','a1t','a1u','a2r','a2s','a2t','a2u','a3r','a3s','a3t','a3u',
'b1r','b1s','b1t','b1u','b2r','b2s','b2t','b2u','b3r','b3s','b3t','b3u']
```

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [combine list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551797/combine-list-elements)

Comment: [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/798854/1324033)

Comment: @ack That question is about `zip`, and the OP needs a cartesian product.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I'd argue theres no point in creating an answer when plenty of duplicates already exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what you want:

```
import itertools

lis = [['a','b'],
       ['1', '2', '3'],
       ['r', 's', 't','u']]

r = ["".join(t) for t in itertools.product(*lis)]
```

This will set `r` to:

```
['a1r', 'a1s', 'a1t', 'a1u', 'a2r', 'a2s', 'a2t', 'a2u', 'a3r', 'a3s', 'a3t', 'a3u', 'b1r', 'b1s', 'b1t', 'b1u', 'b2r', 'b2s', 'b2t', 'b2u', 'b3r', 'b3s', 'b3t', 'b3u']
```

Comment: Cant I achieve that using while/for loop?

Comment: @eishaenan If you hard-wire it to having exactly three sub-lists, then you can use a nest of three loops (`for` loops would be more direct than `while` loops).  If you want it to handle arbitrarily many sub-lists, then you need to keep some state around (the easiest way would be to use a recursive function).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using `itertools`

```
from itertools import product
lis = [['a','b'],
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['r', 's', 't','u']]

l = list(product(*lis))
l = [''.join(x) for x in l]
```

```
Output:

['a1r', 'a1s', 'a1t', 'a1u', 'a2r', 'a2s', 'a2t', 'a2u', 'a3r', 'a3s', 'a3t', 'a3u', 'b1r', 'b1s', 'b1t', 'b1u', 'b2r', 'b2s', 'b2t', 'b2u', 'b3r', 'b3s', 'b3t', 'b3u']
```